# How to prevent js function from execute on page load

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I try to send a confirm post with the `sendPostAjax()` function after the form send_button have been clicked and then submit the form to payment provider. But I get the `sendPostAjax()` function executed on page load, before the click is made.

I have tried to put the `sendPostAjax()` function inside the click catching, but then the promise can not be assigned as the sendPostAjax() function is undefined.

Any suggestions how I should solve this?

**HTML FORM**

```
<form id="payment" method="post" action="https://my-payment-provider.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="charset" value="utf-8">
    // --- additional data here
    <button type="submit" name="submit" id="send_button">PAY</button>
</form>
```

**JAVASCRIPT CODE**

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    // Get click and call sendPostAjax function
    document.getElementById('send_button').addEventListener('click', function () {
        sendPostAjax();
        return false;
    });

    function sendPostAjax() {
        return $.ajax({
            url: 'confirm.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                cid: '9999999'
            }
        });
    }

    // function that expects a promise as an argument:
    function sendForm(x) {
        x.success(function () {
            $('#payment').submit;
        });
    }

    // get a promise from sendPostAjax:
    var promise = sendPostAjax();

    // give a promise to other function:
    sendForm(promise); 
</script>
```

Comment: if you enclose your details inside a <form> tag..then the page will reload on submit.Thats standard <form> behaviour.

Comment: So,if you dont want to reload,Enclose your inputs in a <div> rather than <form> tag.

Comment: MESSIAH: That's not what I asked. The sendPostAjax() function get executed on page load. The form is not sent until button is clicked.

Comment: are you executing you code on dom ready...that might me the reason!!!

Comment: Yes, this is last code on page before </BODY>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `jQuery` button click handler, replace your code with below and try:

Updated code (form submission after `ajax success`):

```
$('#send_button').click(function() {
    var form = $('#payment');
    if (form.attr('confirm') === undefined) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'confirm.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                cid: '9999999'
            },
            success: function(data) {
                form.attr('confirm', '1');
                $('#send_button').click();
            }
        });
        return false;
    }

    return true;
});
```

Comment: Still no post on click, but form get submitted.
I think the form get submitted by the button click, and the post, running asynchronous, never execute.

Comment: You need to prevent form submission to execute `ajax` call, answer updated

Comment: I don't want an alert.

Comment: empty post in console and no post and no form submit.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it...put it right after you have defined both functions

```
   $('#send_button').click(function() {
    // get a promise from sendPostAjax:
    var promise = sendPostAjax();
    // give a promise to other function:
    sendForm(promise);
    });
```

Comment: I tried this, but sendPostAjax() does not execute, so no post get done.